# Ada and assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, ada

I'm looking at making a hardware debug tool that runs on the bare CPU (x86), 32-bit protected mode and no OS.  Due to time constraints, I won't be writing the tool all in x86 assembly. I like the Ada language (but am inexperienced with it) and thought it might be interesting to use Ada rather than C for this project.

With C one can use inline assembly or call subprograms written in assembly to access the BIOS for basic things like keyboard I/O or displaying text on the screen.  Does Ada have a similar capability?  And if so, does anyone know of any resources or tutorials for calling assembly methods and linking with them?

Comment: Why do you insist on not using an OS. Accessing all the hardware (screen, keyboard, etc.) is hard, why not let the OS deal with it. Linux is free ;-)

Comment: Why do I insist?  Well, I'm debugging hardware, not writing Linux software! :p

 I need to do PCI bus resets and modify configuration registers, and .  I've not done much with Linux low-level work, but in the Windows world, parity error(PERR#), system errors (SERR#) and PCI bus reset (RESET#) are catastrophic events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use inline assembly code in Ada. You need to use the `System.Machine_Code` package which provides the (overloaded) `Asm` function.

Answer (score 2):

The GNAT Reference manual has a section on [Machine Code Insertions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Machine-Code-Insertions.html#Machine-Code-Insertions), and while it's GNAT-specific, one should be able to get a general sense of how it works even if you're using a different compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sticking to GNAT as I want to use free tools.  It is a hobby project after all.

Answer (score 0):

Adacore has a section with examples that I found useful.

https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/inline_assembler.html

Note: examples are for 32 bit architecture, use "-m32",
(or change the examples slightly)